# Unable to update pods

Tags: swift, xcode, cocoapods

I am working on existing project .. 
i add another pod in pod file

```
pod 'Firebase/Analytics'
```

and run `pod install` command . It install old version of pod. following are the result of `pod outdated` command.

[image]

following is my pod file

```
  platform :ios, '9.3'
    use_frameworks!

    def shared_pods

    pod 'SwiftyJSON’
    pod 'Kingfisher' #, '4.10.0'
    pod 'Google/Analytics'
    pod 'Fabric'
    pod 'Crashlytics'
    pod 'youtube-ios-player-helper'
    pod 'Firebase/Analytics'
    #    pod 'SlideMenuControllerSwift'
    pod 'XLPagerTabStrip'
end

target 'Project00' do
shared_pods
end

target 'Project01' do
shared_pods
end

target 'Project02' do
shared_pods
end

target 'Project03' do
shared_pods
end

target 'Projec4' do
shared_pods
end
```

after updating the `platform :ios, '9.3'` to `platform :ios, '10.0'` i run `pod update` command and it's only update Kingfisher pod but did't update Firebase pod.

[image]

I also try `sudo gem update cocoapods` command and `cocoapods` is already up to date. and still fail to update Firebase pod. 
I am using Xcode 11.2.1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most likely, some of your other pods have dependencies on specific versions of the pods that are not being updated. My guess would be `"Google/Analytics"`, try removing it and doing a `pod update` again.

`Podfile.lock` should have more info on dependencies and what's going on exactly.

Comment: Thankx alot .. Its work in this case ... but how i come to know which pod need to be removed if face the same thing in other projects  ...

Comment: There's a warning in your first image that Google has been deprecated, that's the one that needs to be removed and replaced with something else.